# How to give space between column and row?

Tags: android, row, space, android-tablelayout

I created one simple table design, I am trying to give space between column and row still its not working?

This is my xml code and screen shot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<TableLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:background="#800000"
            android:text="Today"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView05"
            android:background="#2E8B57"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:text="6:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="Today"
             android:textStyle="bold"  
android:background="#800000"
                        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView05"  
            android:text="6:00"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
         android:background="#00FF7F"

            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"  
            android:text="6:30"  
            android:background="#800000"

            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"  
            android:text="7:00"  
            android:background="#008000"

            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"  
            android:text="7:30"  
            android:background="#FF00FF"

            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="8:00"  
            android:id="@+id/textView1"  
            android:background="#9400D3"

            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
    <TableRow  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  


        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Star Sports"  
            android:id="@+id/textView2"  
            android:background="#00FF7F"

            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView3"  
            android:text="cricket1"  
            android:background="#FF00FF"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="cricket2"  
            android:id="@+id/textView4"  
            android:background="#FFD700"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="cricket3"  
            android:id="@+id/textView5"  
            android:background="#800000"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="cricket4"  
            android:id="@+id/textView6"  
            android:background="#9400D3"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="cricket5"  
            android:id="@+id/textView7"  
            android:background="#008000"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
    <TableRow  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  

        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Ten Sports"  
            android:background="#9400D3"

            android:id="@+id/textView21"  
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Foot Ball1"  
            android:background="#800000"

            android:id="@+id/textView32"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Foot Ball2"  
            android:id="@+id/textView43"  
            android:background="#FF00FF"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Foot Ball3"  
            android:id="@+id/textView54"  
            android:background="#008000"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Foot Ball4"  
            android:background="#FFD700"

            android:id="@+id/textView65"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Foot Ball5"  
            android:id="@+id/textView76"  
            android:background="#00FF7F"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a layout margin for the Textviews where you need space?

Comment: i need space between each cells?

Comment: Try with **padding** attribute in the TextView that you have used in rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try android:layout_margin(Left|Right|Top|Bottom) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This in Between you Cells 
whether it is Column or Row

```
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#716f6f" />
```